# Multiple consecutive text Inputs Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

In a libgdx method I need to preform multiple simple text inputs in a row, like so:

```
Gdx.input.getTextInput(input, "Insert Object Type Here", "block", "");
addInputs[0] = input.lastInput();
Gdx.input.getTextInput(input, "Insert x here", "", "");
addInputs[1] = input.lastInput();
Gdx.input.getTextInput(input, "Insert y here", "", "");
addInputs[2] = input.lastInput();
```

The problem is, the next getTextInput activates before I have time to complete the first one, ending up with multiple text boxes stacked on top of each other, and preventing any of the inputs getting added to the array. I need a way to stop the code entirely, then start it again once I have pressed "OK" on the text input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Simple-text-input):

> The input() method will be called when the user enters a text string.

So you can put the consecutive calls in the `input` method. E.g., something like this:

```
private int inputCalls;
private String[] promptMessages = new String[] {"Insert Object Type Here", "Insert x here", "Insert y here"};

@Override
public void show() {
    // ...
    // First input call
    Gdx.input.getTextInput(new MyTextInputListener(), promptMessages[inputCalls = 0], "block", "");
}

public class MyTextInputListener implements TextInputListener {
   @Override
   public void input (String text) {
       // Keep input value
       addInputs[inputCalls++] = text;
       if (inputCalls < promptMessages.length) {
           // show the subsequent input
           Gdx.input.getTextInput(this, promptMessages[inputCalls], "", "");
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void canceled () {
       Gdx.app.log("Input", "Input canceled");
   }
}
```

Please note I did not run this code, however I hope the idea of the solution I'm suggesting is clear.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, when I go onto the wiki, this answer doesn't show.